# c# mongodb Update single object in nested structure

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have document in mongodb which looks like that.
I want to update only Name on Tag object.
Can you show me how the c# code should looks like to achieve this?

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "111"
    },
    "CustomerId": {
        "$uuid": "123"
    },
    "Products": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a9d0c81cd81383108b26639"
            },
            "ProductId": {
                "$uuid": "555"
            },
            "Name": "test",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "444"
                    },
                    "TagId": {
                        "$uuid": "4676812a-c0f4-62b0-ec36-a2536d58879d"
                    },
                    "Name": "test",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular issue you are having with writing the code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just don't know how to create filter and update in C#  code to create atomic update on a single property on document which consists of multiple nested arrays.

Comment: I know how to update property on single Product.
The code looks like that:
`var update = Builders<Customer>.Update.Set(p => Products[-1].Name, 'new name');
var filter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(c => c.CustomerId, 'id') & Builders<Customer>.Filter.Where(c => c.Products.Any(p => p.ProductId == '555')
collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);`

and it works fine, but the question is how the code should looks like in order to update particular tag name of product